# How to stick a compiled splice into a tag using compiled Heist

Tags: haskell, heist

I created an example repository [here](https://github.com/cideM/heist_getting_started/tree/bb9073f328fcbfcd35b3591fd83835bdd961be44).

The idea is to have a minimal example of using the Haskell templating system Heist without Snap and using its newer compiled Heist feature.

The example repository does not include a server, but the code is intended to be used in a server environment eventually. Therefore, I want to do the following:

1. Pre-compile my splices when the server starts
2. Make a single database call to load all the data for a given view for a REST route (think GET /users)
3. Apply the pre-compiled splices to the data and stick them into a template

For the example repository, step 1 happens at the start of `main`; step 2 is replaced with a simple reader monad; and step 3 is what happens at the bottom of `main`.

It is the last point (3) that I'm struggling with. In the end, I will be calling `C.renderTemplate` with my Heist state and the name of the template. That template will have a tag inside of it, currently called `apply-content` (a bit confusing, since that's from interpeted Heist, but it shouldn't matter I guess). This `apply-content` tag will be replaced with different content by every route. For the purpose of the example repository, I want to take the `body.tpl`, which has a `body-greeting` tag, and replace `apply-content` in `index.tpl` with it.

The only idea I have right now is to modify the list of compiled splices in right before calling `renderTemplate`. But I didn't find any examples of that in the tutorials, nor on GitHub. So I'm inclined to believe that that's not how it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is surprisingly simple.

In compiled mode, you can, and should, [still be making use of the basic template abstractions provided by Heist.](http://snapframework.com/docs/tutorials/heist)

If we replace `body.tpl` with:

```
<apply template="index">
  <p><body-greeting /></p>
</apply>
```

and change `main.hs` so it calls `C.renderTemplate heistState "body"` instead of `"index"`, we get the desired output: the greeting generated at runtime, inserted into the `body` template, which is inserted into the `index` template.

You can see the changes in this [commit](https://github.com/cideM/heist_getting_started/commit/8b65481098811e36a55260fbe812ffdf871672d1)